# Datatype to use for videos in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

The Video size can be in GB's. I am using Longblob but max size that it is allowing is only 2MB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP change the maximum upload file size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Comment: You are aware that MYSQL will use at least 3x the memory when trying to retrieve data of this size right? You're better off saving the video to a file and saving the path in the database.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend storing the video-files in a directory instead of a database, then refer them in the database.
Storing files in the database is usually not recommended. Especially not large files.